# Changing the colour of *some* references

Tags: hyperref, color

I am using

`\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,linktoc=page]{hyperref}`

and the citations come out green, while the page numbers in the table of contents, figure and equation numbers come out blue. These are, as I understand, the standard colours.

How do I *just* keep the green for the citations but change everything else to a non-standard colour? Like, a dark blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set various colours using the `\hypersetup` command (or as optional arguments in `\usepackage[...]{hyperref}`).

In light of the comments I have expanded the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks = true,
  linkcolor =LightSkyBlue,
  anchorcolor = red,
  citecolor = blue,
  urlcolor = blue
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}\label{One}1+1=2\end{equation}
  Isn't \ref{One} a nice equation?
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

See the [hyperref manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) for details on the possible options.

Comment: If I want to use a non-standard colour, where should I define it? Before the hypersetup package is loaded?

Comment: @SuperCiocia You may load `xcolor` before `hyperref` and define your own colors.